# JavaScript not assigning an element to the object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

```
const allocation_me = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { user: userid } = request;
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(userid)) throw new Error('invalid objectid');

    const now = moment().format();
    const date = new Date(now);
    const allocation = await Allocation.findOne({ $and: [{ user: userid, start_date: { $lt: date }, end_date: { $gt: date } }] })
      .populate('user', 'name')
      .populate('garden');
    if (!allocation) throw new Error('invalid request');
    allocation.timestamp = moment(allocation.end_date).format('x');
    response.status(200).send(allocation);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send(error);
  }
};
```

I'm trying to add the timestamp to the object that is returned by the mongo query but when it sends the allocation as the response, the timestamp doesn't show up. I've tried to log the allocation.timestamp value and it doesn't show either, it's like javascript is ignoring me assigning it. I've tried changing from const to let but apparently that's not the issue.

Comment: One more thing you can do here it to use `.lean()`... Something like this `.populate('user', 'name')
      .populate('garden').lean()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...it's like javascript is ignoring me assigning it.

That's entirely possible, if the allocation object is [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) by MongoDB.

Instead, make a copy and add your property to the copy, perhaps with ES2018's property spread:

```
allocation = {...allocation, timestamp: moment(allocation.end_date).format('x')};
```

...or if you can't use property spread, `Object.assign`:

```
allocation = Object.assign({}, allocation, {timestamp: moment(allocation.end_date).format('x')});
```

You'll need to change `const` to `let` in both of those cases, since we're changing the value held by the variable `allocation`. Or of course, leave it as a `const` and remember the modified version separately:

```
const updatedAllocation = {...allocation, timestamp: moment(allocation.end_date).format('x')};
response.status(200).send(updatedAllocation);
```

---

> I've tried changing from const to let but apparently that's not the issue.

Correct. `const` applies to the **variable** (`allocation`), not the object the variable refers to.

Comment: `allocation = {...allocation._doc, timestamp: moment(allocation.end_date).format('x')};` worked perfectly. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Documents returned from the query are mongoose/mongodb documents not the plain javascript objects.

So to modify anything in the returned document you have to either assign it to `new Object()` or you can use [**`.lean()`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option which converts mongoose object to the plain javascript object.

```
const allocation = await Allocation.findOne({})
      .populate('user', 'name')
      .populate('garden')
      .lean()
if (!allocation) throw new Error('invalid request');
allocation.timestamp = moment(allocation.end_date).format('x');
```