# Object property is not getting assigned in the result of mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have executed a mongoose find query and stored the result in the object.

```
var enabledPlayerQuery = playerCollection.find({playerMobile:{$gt:0}})
```

Then on that object, I have done exec operation like this to add a total coin's value in every object but on the console when I use to print the object it shows the value is not getting assigned. The object remains in the previous state as before.

```
enabledPlayerQuery.exec(function(err,queryResult){ 
    async.each(queryResult, function(users ,result){
        user.totalCoins = 1000;
    }, function(err){
        //anything console
    })
}
```

But the total coins value is not getting assigned.

I tried to do _.extend method to extend both the objects. Also created another object and pasted the property of the previous one to that and then also it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript not assigning an element to the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425107/javascript-not-assigning-an-element-to-the-object)

Answer (score 2):

The mongoose find query returns a mongoose object and not JS object. Hence you cant assign a key to the returned object which is not defined in your mongoose schema for `playerCollection` model. To do this you need to convert this mongoose document into a JS object by either using `lean()` in the find query itself :

```
var enabledPlayerQuery = playerCollection.find({playerMobile:{$gt:0}}).lean()
```

or by using `toObject()` on the resultant object.

```
enabledPlayerQuery.exec(function(err,queryResult){ 
    async.each(queryResult, function(users ,result){
        user.toObject()
        user.totalCoins = 1000;
    }, function(err){
        //anything console
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.lean()` in this case. It will give you a plain object where you can utilise the features of object manipulation.

```
var enabledPlayerQuery = playerCollection.find({playerMobile:{$gt:0}}).lean()
```

The original output preserves the schema format that you are using to fetch values from the collection.