# Why i can`t change my object with .map from mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I'm trying to write a new version of the date in the object.
Everything is output to the console correctly, but the resulting object is simply not overwritten.

```
Aircraft.find({leave: true}, (err, resp) => {
    result = resp;

    result = result.map((obj) => {
        let tmp = new Date(obj.timeArrival);
        tmp = moment(obj.timeArrival).format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY');
        console.log(obj.timeArrival); // 2016-05-18T16:00:00.000Z
        console.log(tmp); // Wednesday, May 18 2016
        obj.timeArrival = tmp;
        console.log(obj.timeArrival); // 2016-05-18T16:00:00.000Z
        return obj;
    })
    res.render("departed.hbs", {
        us: result
    });
})
```

`result` still old!

Comment: `console.log(obj.timeArrival); ` the second console shows the old value inside the loop ?

Comment: yes, exactly as comment

Comment: Have you tried using `lean()` as `Aircraft.find({ leave: true }).lean().exec(function(err, resp) {
  ...
});`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript not assigning an element to the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425107/javascript-not-assigning-an-element-to-the-object)

Comment: I tested an adapted version of your code and it worked as expected, both setting 'Wednesday, May 18 2016' to a string field or a Date field.

Comment: Using .lean() will probably solve your problem, but for the sake of comedy:

The only thing that did not work for me was setting an unparsable date-string (e.g. 'test') to the date field. Mongoose ignored this, without a warning. 

Can you please drop your whole dev-database and try again? If that does not help, can you post your Aircraft schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new json object inside the map function.

```
Aircraft.find({leave: true}, (err, resp) => {
  result = resp;

  result = result.map((obj) => {
    var new_obj = {};
    new_obj = obj;
    let tmp = new Date(obj.timeArrival);
    tmp = moment(obj.timeArrival).format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY');
    console.log(obj.timeArrival); // 2016-05-18T16:00:00.000Z
    console.log(tmp); // Wednesday, May 18 2016
    new_obj.timeArrival = tmp;
    console.log(obj.timeArrival); // 2016-05-18T16:00:00.000Z
    return new_obj ;
  })
  res.render("departed.hbs", {
    us: result
  });
})
```